# Error installing mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I'm trying to set up my RubyOnRails development enviroment with MySQL. I have XAMPP installed, so I decided to use the XAMPP's MySQL installation, (therefore I installed the XAMPP dev package).

Now I'm trying to install the mysql2 gem but I got this error:

```
gem install mysql2 --version 0.2.7 -- --with-mysql-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ --with-mysql-lib=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/ –with-mysql-include=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql/ --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config 
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/yard-0.6.3/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": undefined method `overwrite_accessor' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ --with-mysql-lib=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/ –with-mysql-include=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql/ --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql  -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c client.c
gcc -I. -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql  -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c mysql2_ext.c
./client.h:20: warning: ‘rb_thread_blocking_region’ defined but not used
./client.h:20: warning: ‘rb_thread_blocking_region’ defined but not used
./client.h:20: warning: ‘rb_thread_blocking_region’ defined but not used
gcc -I. -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin10.0 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql  -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c result.c
cc -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o mysql2.bundle client.o mysql2_ext.o result.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch x86_64  -Wl,-rpath,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib    -lruby -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.4  -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm  -lpthread -ldl  
ld: -rpath can only be used when targeting Mac OS X 10.5 or later
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

So I think the key point here is:

```
ld: -rpath can only be used when targeting Mac OS X 10.5 or later
```

I've tried to set the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 but nothing changes.

By the way, I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.6, so the error above doesn't make any sense...

Thank you!

Comment: I can't speak to this issue in any other implementation but it is known issue in JRUBY. see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several possibilities you could try.

1. Try adding `--platform=ruby` to your command.  I've seen that people claim it helps.

   Your command should then be:

   ```
   gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby --version 0.2.7 -- --with-mysql-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ --with-mysql-lib=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/ –with-mysql-include=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql/ --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
   ```
2. Make sure you are building for the correct architecture.  OSX 10.6.x is very vague about when it uses 32-bit stuff and when it uses 64-bit stuff, at least as far as I can tell.

   You need to try building against both 32 and 64 bit versions of MySQL.

   The simplest way to do it is to download both of them from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads and try to build against each one.